Adaptative header in parallel typesetting
I am working on a bilingual document with the original text and translation on facing pages, using reledmac and reledpar. Parallel divisions of the text are of course using the same number on both sides.
I would like a fancyhdr header to provide the current division of the original text. I tried to use and adapt the solution provided by Maïeul in this thread, which essentially consists in renewing the sectionning mechanism like this :\newcommand{\division}[1]{#1.\markboth{#1}{#1}}. Once this is done, we can simply ask fancyhdr to adapt the header according to the divisions on the current page: \fancyhead[C]{\rightmark-\leftmark}
However, the suggested method only works in a non-parallel environement. When producing parallel \Pages, it seems reledpar first typesets the leftpage (where the desired behaviour occurs), then the corresponding rightpage. But while doing so, it keeps in memory the last \leftmark of the leftpage as the first mark of the rightpage. So, beyond the first page of the parallel document, the header does not display the current division of the leftpage text correctly.
Here is a MWE adaptated from Maïeul's example. I make fancyhdr print the division number on both sides to show how the problem seems to happen:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{reledmac} 
\usepackage[advancedshiftedpstarts]{reledpar}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L,R]{}%Reset header
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[C]{Liber antiquus, \rightmark-\leftmark}% In the center, print main title, then division


\newcommand{\division}[1]{#1.\doinsidethislinehook{\markboth{#1}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}%first page is blank for parallel typesetting
\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}% On this side, I will get the correct range of divisions in the header, 1-5
\beginnumbering
\pstart[\newpage]
\division{1} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\pend
\pstart
\division{2} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\pend

\pstart
\division{3}
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{4}
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{5}
s
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}% This side will print an incorrect range of divisions, 5-5...
\beginnumbering
\pstart[\newpage]
\division{1}%...although I reset the first division number to 1
Translated dummy text
\pend
\pstart
\division{2}
Translated dummy text
\pend 
\pstart
\division{3}
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{4}
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{5}
s
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}

How can I keep the advantage of the division mechanism from the leftpage for my header, while making fancyhdr (or reledpar?) ignore the division numbers from the rightpage?
EDIT : Updating TeXLive to the 2024 version solved the issue, thanks to @marquinho.

Which LaTeX distribution are you using? I've got TeXLive 2024 and 2021 on my machine: With TL 2024, your example compiles as intended and gives "Liber antiquus, 1-5" on both pages. With TL 2021, I see the issue that you describe ("5-5" on the right page). The issue was likely fixed in reledmac in the meantime: I think you might want to update your distribution.

Thank you! I was indeed still running the 2021 version from the Linux Mint repository. Clean install of the newest version solved the issue.

Answering this for future reference:
Your approach is good as it stands and is in fact the recommended practice as of 2024.
You followed @Maïeul's official approach:

For parallel typesetting with reledpar, see your quoted thread from 2018/2019;
for reledmac at large, see the manual, sec. 5.6 and 5.7.

Note that the essential ingredient (that you didn't explicitly mention in the question) is the command \doinsidethislinehook{ }, without which we'd run into problems with the header marks.
Thus, the complete command to provide fancyhdr with the updated marks, would be something like:
\newcommand{\division}[1]{#1.\doinsidethislinehook{\markboth{#1}{#1}}}

and the complete setup looks like this:
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{My custom divisions: \rightmark-\leftmark}
\newcommand{\division}[1]{#1.\doinsidethislinehook{\markboth{#1}{#1}}}

A superficial explanation of the issue you were experiencing is that,
apparently, at some time in the past this solution stopped working. Specifically, with a 2021 TeX distribution, reledmac(par) didn't play nice with fancyhdr.
Arguably, this is all we need to know, since as of the 2024 distribution, the kinks were ironed out. An old bug(?)/issue from 2021 is moot today and even more so if anyone reads this in the future.
